# Calculation by group in one column R

Tags: r, aggregate

```
group=c("A","A","B","A","B","C","C","A")
y=c(3,4,5,2,1,4,1,2)
df=data.frame(group,y)
```

using `aggregate`, I can get the average by

```
aggregate(df$y, list(df$group), mean)
```

But my question is: How to do something like : `(y_ij-mean_i)`
where `mean_i` is the average for group `i`

thank you.

Comment: I would guess `y - with(df, ave(y, group))`

Comment: or `with(df, ave(y, group, FUN=function(x) {x-mean(x)}))` (= `ave(df$y, df$group, FUN=function(x) {x-mean(x)})`)

Comment: or with `dplyr`,  `df %>%  group_by(group) %>%  mutate(mean_y = y - mean(y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ave`

```
 with(df, y- ave(y, group))
```